# Алгоритм замены цифр буквами?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть ID, который по заданию не может иметь пять цифр. Только четыре. Когда он достигает 9999 (четыре знака) нужно, например, заменять 10,11,12.. на A,B,C.. то есть на выходе мне надо число 10000 представить так А000. 10999->A999, 11267->B267 и т.д.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Что вы уже попробавли и что не получилось?

Comment: Просто перевести в 16-ричную систему не подходит?

Comment: Ну, переведите 1000000 в 16-ричную)

Comment: @KonstantinKožuchov, а как миллион будет представлен в вашей системе замен?

Comment: @KonstantinKožuchov вы просите в 4 знаках уместить бесконечность?:)

Comment: @KonstantinKožuchov, не хотите 16-ричную - переводите в 36-ричную

Comment: @АндрейNOP Именно так и решил сделать 36,36,36,36. На несколько лет хватит)

Comment: @myxaxa нет конечно, лишь максимально возможное:)

Comment: @KonstantinKožuchov, можете использовать китайский алфавит - хватит ещё надольше:)

Comment: @myxaxa идея хорошая, использовать её я конечно не буду.

Comment: Согласно вашей постановке задачи, заменять на буквы разрешается только самый старший разряд. Каким образом вдруг получилось `36,36,36,36`?

Comment: @AnT 0-9 + 'A - Z'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переведите число в 36-ричную систему счисления, пример на C#:

```
static string ToBase36(int value)
{
    var b = 36;
    var s = 4;
    char[] c = new char[s];
    for (int i = s - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        var r = value % b;
        value /= b;
        c[i] = (char)(r < 10 ? '0' + r : 'A' + r - 10);
        // Или, кому нравится:
        // c[i] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[r];
    }
    return new string(c);
}
```

1000000 отображается как LFLS

Comment: алфавит не проще было в строку записать и по индексу `r` обращаться?

Comment: @teran, хотел сначала в строчку, но 36 слишком длинно, поэтому сделал так. Это плохо?

Comment: да там нагляднее просто, имхо. + в принципе позволяет использовать вообще произвольные символы, либо изменить их порядок и т.п.

Comment: @teran, добавил

Comment: В вопросе сказано, что `11267` должно стать `B267`. Ваша функция так переводит?

Comment: @AnT, автор уже передумал, ему ведь нужно покрыть числа вплоть до 1000000

Answer (score 1):

Проведи деление id без остатка на 1000.
Получившееся число преобразуй в 16ричное.
Скрепи результат с  отстатком от деления на 1000

Answer (score 0):

Для неотрицательных чисел алгоритм такой:

- Числа меньше 10000 оставляем как есть
- Числа до 36000

  - Первую букву определяем, прибавив к бкуве `A` число полных тысяч в числе и вычитая 10 (они уже заняты цифрами - нам надо 10 превратить в `A`, 11 - в `B`)
  - Остальные 3 цифры берём как последние цифры самого числа (или остатка от деления его на 1000); только надо быть осторожным и не забыть про нули - ноль должен превратиься в `000`, а не в `0`
- Остальные числа мы так представить не можем

```js
function transform(x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    return "0"
  }

  if (x < 10000) {
    return x + ""
  }
  
  if (x < 36000) {
    return (
      String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) - 10 + Math.floor(x / 1000))
      + ("00" + x % 1000).slice(-3)
    )
  }
  
  return "####"
}

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  document.querySelector("output").textContent = transform(+e.target.value)
})
```

```css
* { font-family: monospace; }
output { display: inline-block; width: 4ch; text-align: right; }
```

```html
<input type=number> <output>
```

Ну и если бы мне захотелось написать это покомпактнее:

```js
function transform(x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    return 0
  }

  if (x < 10000) {
    return x
  }
  
  if (x < 36000) {
    return Math.floor(x / 1000).toString(36).toUpperCase() + (x + "").slice(-3)
  }
  
  return "####"
}

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  document.querySelector("output").textContent = transform(+e.target.value)
})
```

```css
* { font-family: monospace; }
output { display: inline-block; width: 4ch; text-align: right; }
```

```html
<input type=number> <output>
```